# Application health monitoring in Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, health-monitoring

Systemd will create a process & which in-turn creates many other applications/processes at startup, that need to run on my embedded device.

1. Is there any way we can add a piece of code in all the applications such that systemd will exchange 'heartbeat' & will know if some application is hung or not
2. Is there some examples which I can refer & understand?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **yes**, [see this superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/689017/can-systemd-detect-and-kill-hung-processes):

> **Yes; but first fix your buggy program before fiddling with systemd.**
>   MariusMatutiae is quite correct. You have a problem with your program.
>   It deadlocks. Fiddling with systemd isn't the answer. At best, it's a
>   distraction. Fix your program so that it isn't broken. Direct your
>   energies at the right thing.
>
> That said, other people are going to come here because of the question
>   title, rather than the question proper. For their benefit, here's the
>   answer to the title, ignoring the question proper:
>
> Yes, systemd can monitor dæmons and automatically restart them if they
>   stop talking. Not just any old dæmons, though. As mvp notes, there's
>   no way to know that a dæmon has hung (in this universe, where the
>   halting problem is undecidable, at least). Neither systemd nor any
>   other computer program will ever be capable of deducing from scratch
>   that some random program thrown at them has deadlocked, or gone into
>   an infinite loop, or whatever. The best that you'll get here is
>   detecting that a dæmon hasn't performed a regular "heartbeat"
>   operation within a required timespan.
>
> Dæmons that take advantage of systemd's watchdog capabilities,
>   therefore, have to be written to speak a systemd-specific protocol,
>   the sd_notify protocol. This complicates the dæmon code a tad. It's
>   complicated further because dæmons should, if written properly, check
>   whether they've been invoked with the watchdog function enabled, as
>   well.
>
> A dæmon that speaks this protocol to make use of systemd's watchdog
>   capability …
>
> - … must check for the WATCHDOG_USEC environment variable;
> - … must call [sd_notify()](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html) continually and frequently, throughout its lifetime, with the WATCHDOG=1 option set, at an interval of about WATCHDOG_USEC/2 ("USEC" stands for microseconds) ;
> - … must have [Type=notify](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) set in its unit file;
> - … should have [NotifyAccess=main](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#NotifyAccess=) (or =all) set in its unit file;
> - … must have [WatchdogSec=seconds](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#WatchdogSec=) set in its unit file.
> - … must link with libsystemd-daemon.so If you want to know the details of coding this, after reading the manual, make sure that you go to the right StackExchange. This is SuperUser. StackOverflow is [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sd_notify).
>
> **Further reading**
>
> - Lennart Poettering. 2011-04-12. [Watchdogs](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html). Freedesktop.org.